# how to change the gridview row value after button click event

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, ado.net

I have a table in four columns see screenshot here:

[image]

But I need two columns in that table name and gender see screenshot here:

[image]

Display in this type but I have required after click the button row value will change in GridView button out side in GridView e.g. row value 1,2 can instead  male and female that is my requirement.

Comment: its not a freelancer site, you should try something yourself and then ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch that data from database in dataset or datatable and assign that as DataSource to the GridView and call DataBind on that GridView. Now in RowDataBound event compare the value and assign value to UI label / literal based on that.

Below is GridView in aspx page.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Literal ID="ltrlEmpName" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee Gender">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Literal ID="ltrlEmpGender" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In code behind, lets say you want to assign the datasource to this GridView in page load or any other method. Below will be its code. Note that in sample here I have taken dummy DataTable and filled values for simplicity, you need to fill that DataTable from db values.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Dummy data table below, that needs to be replaced by datatable / dataset fetched from database.
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EmpName", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EmpGender", typeof(int)));

            DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
            dr1["EmpName"] = "Romesh";
            dr1["EmpGender"] = 1;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr1);

            DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
            dr2["EmpName"] = "Sandya";
            dr2["EmpGender"] = 2;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr2);

            // Bind the datasource to gridview.
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal ltrlEmpName = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal)e.Row.FindControl("ltrlEmpName");
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal ltrlEmpGender = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal)e.Row.FindControl("ltrlEmpGender");

                // Bind employee name to its label.
                ltrlEmpName.Text = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "EmpName"));

                // Bind employee gender to its label based on its value.
                if (Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "EmpGender")) == "1")
                {
                    ltrlEmpGender.Text = "Male";
                }
                else if (Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "EmpGender")) == "2")
                {
                    ltrlEmpGender.Text = "Female";
                }
                else
                {
                    ltrlEmpGender.Text = "Other";
                }
            }
        }
```

You will get out as Table as below.

[image]

Comment: 'ASP.gradedividing_aspx' does not contain a definition for 
   'GridView1_RowDataBound' and no extension method 'GridView1_RowDataBound' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.gradedividing_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\romesh\GridviewTutorial\GradeDividing.aspx

Comment: have you place "protected void GridView1_RowDataBound...." mentioned in my answer in your .cs file?